# Is there an R command to trigger the download of a file from Rstudio Server?

Tags: r, rstudio, rstudio-server

When working with Rstudio Server, it is very easy to download a file from the server with File>More>Export... The web browser will automatically start downloading.

Is there a way to generate this download with an R command ?

Comment: I don't know that there's been much progress on an RStudio API, as of yet, which would allow you to do RStudio-specific calls like that. I think the best approach would be to use the URL approach like Spacedman recommends.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does browseURL do it for you:

```
browseURL                package:utils                 R Documentation

Load URL into a WWW Browser

Description:

     Load a given URL into a WWW browser.

Usage:

     browseURL(url, browser = getOption("browser"), encodeIfNeeded = FALSE)
```

That should fire it up in a browser. To download directly in R, `download.file` is what you want, but that hangs the command line until complete.

Comment: It works when I give the ftp path to the file as the URL. Many thanks !

Comment: @nassimhddd - dumb Q on my part I know but how would I find the ftp path? - it doesn't look instinctive within the RStudio Server UI. Much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Sometimes when I wanted to download a binary `rds` file, Safari would display it in a new tab.  If I used `zip::zip(mode = "cherry-pick")` then Safari would instead download the zip file to my Downloads folder and then automatically unzip it.