# Code Behind RStudio Server Export Function

Tags: linux, r, rstudio-server

I am currently using RStudio-server on `Linux redhat`. One nice feature of RStudio-server is that I can export from the server to my `Windows` desktop. Does anyone know the code behind the export drop-down?

The export function can be found via the `Files` tab:
`(More >> Export...)`

I would like use code to automate the exporting of objects. I figured I should be able to perform this export using the `system` function, but I am having trouble.

Thanks for any help.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think this  [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11649224/is-there-an-r-command-to-trigger-the-download-of-a-file-from-rstudio-server) might help you,

Spacedman explains that you can trigger the export by the use of the R function "browseURL", with the URL parameter replaced by the ftp path to the file.

If you absolutely want to trigger this export with a system command, perhaps you could create an R script taking as parameter the file to export and launch that script with the system() function =) Although I can't see clearly the advantages of such a process.

[edit] : After having tried it today, I realise my answer wasn't complete :

If you try the function browseURL on files such as "whateverRscript.r", it will display it in a tab of your browser, rather than trigger the download.

In order to actually make your browser download this kind of file, maybe you can zip it first.

To complete the automation process, just change the parameters of your browser such that it won't "ask everytimes where to stock the downloaded files"

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me: run it on Server side. Working browser is required (I used Chrome)

```
my_data_file_name <- "data.RData"
# set file name

save(Data, file=my_data_file_name)
# save data to file

current_dir <- getwd()
# capture current working directory on server

my_export_file_path <- paste0(current_dir, '/', my_data_file_name)
# create a path for file to export

browseURL(my_export_file_path)
# export to local disk using browser's capabilities
```