# Export file from R server to local disk- code

Tags: r, server, export

It is possible to copy file form R server to local disc?
I can do this via button (MORE--> Export) but i wanna do this using code.

Anyone can help me?
[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBy1p.jpg)

Comment: Perhaps you could ssh/scp/ftp onto the server and download like that?

Comment: I wanna do it automatically but dont know how. Maybe coud do it using R script?

Comment: Yes, you could write an R script which runs scp, logins onto the server and downloads the data. :)

Answer (score 2):

I am having same question exactly, and have found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981862/code-behind-rstudio-server-export-function)

Do you know your R Server's path?
You are able to find full path easily. If you choose an image file in [Files] tab, open the file on the browser maybe.

And then, type this. That's it.

`browseURL("http://yourhost:portnumber/files/yourpath/filename.xlsx")`